# live streaming from android studio app to a website

Tags: android, live-streaming

I am creating an android studio app for my final year project. A feature that I want in the app is live streaming from the android studio app on a mobile to a website. 
I am a bit stuck. I don't know what way to go about it. Any help would be great.

Comment: first tell us what you want to stream? Video? Sound? Device desktop? Fried potatos?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question seems vague. [How to ask proper question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for getting back to me so soon. Sorry i'm new to this. 
So basically I want to create an android studio app that can stream a live video from a mobile device to a website that relates to the app.